# TensorFlow: using F1_score in context of a binary classification

Tags: tensorflow, classification, floating-accuracy, softmax

I'm using a softmax function for a binary classification task.
My test label is a one hot list and looks like:
    test_y = [[1. 0.] [1. 0.]…]

And the predicted label is a probability list:

```
test_y_pred = [[  4.39091297e-09   1.00000000e+00]
        [  1.75207238e-10   1.00000000e+00] …]
```

When I try to use the f1_score, I get an error :

ValueError: Can't handle mix of binary and continuous

How can I handle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

f1_score will not classify the results for you.

Change your predictions to vectors of classes, for example:

```
import numpy as np
test_y = [np.argmax(prediction) for prediction in test_y]
test_y_pred= [np.argmax(prediction) for prediction in test_y_pred]
```